# Checking if user account is confirmed by email code With unnecessary logging in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel project, where I try implement checking if user account is confirmed by activation code from user's email:

```
public function SignIn(Request $request){

        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {



            if(Auth::user()->status==false){

                Auth::logout();
                Session::flash('activationError','First please active your account');
                return back();

            }

            return redirect()->route('showDashboardWelcome');
        }

        else{

            Session::flash('loginError','Your username and password are wrong');
            return back();
        }
    }
```

In above code there is function from controller to Sign in user. This function check if the user email and password are correct and if user has confirmed account($status variable from user model with two boolean values) by email code.

If account is not confirmed by user I must logout user from account, because function attempt start simultaneously user's session. Is there any possible way to do this operation without starting a user session and then logout user?

I would be grateful for help. Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a middleware to directly query the users table and check the status field. If not verified redirect away to the page showing the message. For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckVerified
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if (!user->status) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('not verified');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass as many parameters to `attempt([])` as you want. So here you can add 'status' to the array like this

```
if(Auth::attempt([
    'email' => $request['email'], 
    'password' => $request['password'], 
    'status' => true
])) {

}
```

Every single parameter you pass to that array has to be met for the `Auth::attemp()` to start the session.

Comment: OK, but your solution isn't enough because I don't know how distiguish message for user when he has wrong password and email and when he has not activated account.

Comment: Then you can change your login logic. 1. Get the user by email. 2. Check the user status 3. Login the user. And done. No need for extra middleware just to check for something once. Middleware are good for stuff you need to check most of the time like the session, the token, etc.